# Django - Get ContentType model by model name (Generic Relations)

Tags: python, django, content-type

I'm thinking about this for a while now,

I'm creating a chat application, in chat.models a class Room is specified, however, a Room can be related to anything in my project, since it uses a generic relation in it's foreign key.

Is there a way to know which model that Room is related knowing only the models name?

Like:

```
ctype = 'user'

related_to_user = Room.objects.filter(content_type=ctype)
```

The problem I'm having is, the code below is in a view:

```
doc = get_object_or_404(Document, id=id)
# get *or create* a chat room attached to this document
room = Room.objects.get_or_create(doc)
```

If I don't want to use Document model, if I want a model associated to a string, a string that can be anything, without having to write tons of if's to get a specific Model for the specific string. Is there a way to find a model just by it's 'name'?

Thanks

Answer (score 59, accepted):

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#methods-on-contenttype-instances

```
user_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label="auth", model="user")
user_type = ContentType.objects.get(model="user")
# but this can throw an error if you have 2 models with the same name.
```

Very similar to django's `get_model`

```
from django.db.models import get_model
user_model = get_model('auth', 'user')
```

To use your example exactly:

```
ctype = ContentType.objects.get(model='user')
related_to_user = Room.objects.filter(content_type=ctype)
```

Comment: is there a way to find out which app a model is from IF there's only one model with that name?

Comment: Sure, `contenttype.app_label`

Comment: I mean, not having the model, just it's name string, look in the database for a app that has that model. I tried what you sad, with not much success

Comment: `app_string = ContentType.objects.get(model="model_string").app_label`? What is the end goal here? What are you looking for?

Comment: I realized what I was doing wrong, thanks you all. I was entering model string like 'Room', and it wasn't finding any model... However 'room' found what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: note: line should be ContentType.objects.get(app_label="auth", model="user")

Comment: Good to mention that ContentType.objects.get_for_model(User) better than simple ContentType.objects.get(...) because it's have internal cache