# Django ContentType in form.html

Tags: python, django, django-contenttypes

I want to add **favourite** functionality to my app and since many models can be favourited I will do it with [ContentType framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) in **Django**.

My problem is, that I don't know how to get a `content_type` of a model from form?

**View:**

```
@login_required
def add_or_remove(request):

    user = request.user

    try:
        app_model = request.POST["target_model"]
        obj_id = int(request.POST["target_object_id"])
    except (KeyError, ValueError):
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()

    fav = Favorite.objects.get_favorite(user, obj_id, model=app_model)

    if fav is None:
        Favorite.objects.create(user, obj_id, app_model)

    return HttpResponse('Done!')
```

**Form (form.html)**

```
<form action="" action="POST">
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ object.id}}" name="target_object_id">
    <input type="hidden" value="?" name="target_model">
</form>
```

So, I know how to get an `object_id` and `user`, but how do I display an `app_model` in a form?
I've read the docs but I don't really get it.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120071/django-get-contenttype-model-by-model-name-generic-relations

Answer (score 0):

You can display `ContentType` id.

Get the id for display in the form: `ContentType.objects.get_for_model(TargetModelClass).pk`.

Get the model from the id: `ContentType.objects.get_for_id(int(request.POST["target_model"]))`